# How to insert unique table data except id in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can insert the unique row in mysql?
id and userid both are different column.
I have set id is unique.But userid and checkin column should not be repeated.
Is this possible?

```
if($this->dx_auth->is_logged_in()){
    $insertData['userid']     = $this->dx_auth->get_user_id();
    $insertData['checkin']    = $checkin;
    $insertData['checkout']   = $checkout;
    $insertData['location']   = $location;
    $insertData['guest']      = $nof_guest;
    $id = $this->dx_auth->get_user_id();
    $result = $this->Common_model->getTableData('searchlist', array("userid" => $id));
    if($result->num_rows > 4){
        $res = $result->result();
        $del_id = $res[0]->id;
        $conditions = array("id" => $del_id);
        $this->Common_model->deleteTableData('searchlist', $conditions);
    } 
    if($location != "0"){
    $this->Common_model->inserTableData('searchlist', $insertData);}}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? I'm really not understanding you.

Comment: Perhaps, also add what the table looks like and what you want it too like.

Comment: I should check the repeated userid and checkin data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your `id` as primary key and auto increment for your user table.

Then, you have to create combined unique key for `userid` and `checkin`.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_checkin_time ON searchlist (userid, checkin);
```

In controller, you have to validate the userid and checkin before insert / update.

```
$isExist = $this->Common_model->getTableData('searchlist', array("userid" => $id,"checkin"=>$checkin));
if($isExist->num_rows()>0)
{
  // throw error message as checkin time already exist
}
else
{
   // continue with further code
}
```

Comment: If i give userid is vary but checkin is same it is not accepted :( I need when I give userid and checkin is same that time only it should not accept.?

Comment: In getTableData(), are you checking condition with `or`? If so, change it as `and`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can really make the `userid` and `checkin` columns as a composite primary key. If you want you can still use `id` as the primary key and create a unique index for the 2 other columns combined.

You should probably also check if the record exists before you insert a new combination that would result in a MySQL error.

Cheers!